# Unexpected behavior of grep in bash regarding lines preceded with several same characters

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am playing [bandit](https://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/) from [overthewire.org](https://overthewire.org); [getting to level 10](https://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/bandit10.html) requires me to find strings preceded with several "=" characters (equal sign) (I interpreted "several" as "two or more") in a text file.

The target lines look like this:

`========== passwordhere123`

i.e. ten equal signs, one space, and a string of letters and numbers, followed by line break (not sure which exact type).

These lines should be excluded:

`c========== EqualSignDidNotStartLine`

`= only-one-equal-sign`

`equalsign=somewhereElse`

`No equal signs at all`

The original data did not contain any lines preceded by less than ten but more than one ='s; there are some +'s (plus signs) littered in the text, but +'s and ='s are never in the same line.

The bandit server runs some kind of linux @ 4.18.12 (uname -r), GNU bash 4.4 (from man page), and GNU grep 2.27 (from man page).

The raw data contains non-readable parts, so it is fed through `strings` first to leave only human-readable strings fro grep to process.

From what I learned, grep's default regex engine (BRE, thanks [Casimir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte)) should not be too different from PCRE's. `*` is still a quantifier (match the preceding pattern zero times or more), not as a standalone pattern meaning "anything, zero times or more". This confuses me in grep's behavior below.

**Edit:** per [this chart](https://remram44.github.io/regex-cheatsheet/regex.html#syntax-multiplicity), "+" needs to be escaped (i.e.`\+`) in BRE. It does not help though. I will make some more testing strings to try to decipher what's going on.

Here's the command I tried:

```sh
strings data.txt | grep -P -e ^==+.*

strings data.txt | grep -P -e ^==+.*$ #both PCRE expressions worked correctly

#start BRE

strings data.txt | grep -e ^==.*    #includes every line preceded by at least two =; works

strings data.txt | grep -e ^==.*$   #includes every line preceded by at least two =; works

strings data.txt | grep -e ^==+.*   #no output; why?

strings data.txt | grep -e ^==+.*$  #no output

strings data.txt | grep -e ^==+*    #includes every target line, so works; WHY IS THIS A LEGAL REGEX?

strings data.txt | grep -e ^==+*$   #no output

strings data.txt | grep -e ^==\+.*  #no output

strings data.txt | grep -e ^==\+.*$ #no output

strings data.txt | grep -e ^==\+*   #includes every target line, so works

strings data.txt | grep -e ^==\+*$  #no output
```

Comment: grep uses the BRE (Basic Regular Expression) syntax by default, search that with your favorite search engine.

Comment: Please show us the *exact* copy-and-pasted commands you tried. In your question, you've mispelled `strings` as `strings` and `-e` as `ie`. We can't tell which errors are in your original commands and which are transcription errors. The regular expression should be enclose in single quotes so the shell doesn't try to expand it. It looks like at least some of your confusion has to do with the `+` character; with `grep -P` or `grep -E` (`egrep`), it means one or more occurrences, but in a basic regular expression it has no special meaning.

Comment: also quote your regex to prevent bash globbing.

Comment: I hope there is no misspells now... These should be all commands I tried. My confusion is mainly around ```+``` and ```*```. I think in ```^==+*```, the ```*``` quantifies ```+``` so essentially it didn't matter in the text provided; I could have used ```^==``` and get the same result. And ```^===*.*``` could have be used to avoid messing with ```+```. But what about ```\+```?

Comment: OK... so I think can contribute most my issues to shell messing with unquoted regex. Testing the regex's in quotes made much more sense.

Comment: That chart you referenced seems to be talking about GNU tools, not POSIX. In a POSIX BRE `\+` means the same as `+`, i.e. a literal `+` character, it's only GNU tools that treat `\+` in a BRE context to mean the same as `+` in an ERE context. In a POSIX BRE to get `1-or-more` repetitions you write `\{1,\}`. Several of the other escape sequences only apply to GNU tools and some only apply to specific tools, GNU, POSIX or otherwise. It's not a great source of definitive information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd be worried about shell expansion.  From long experience, I put regexs on the command line in 'single quotes', to avoid meta-character madness.

Second, this (under BRE):

```
^==+*
```

is perfectly valid.  It means:

```
^     anchored at the start of the input
==    followed by 2 '=' charaters
+*    followed by 0 or more '+' characters
```

You stated **"From what I learned, grep's default regex engine (BRE, thanks Casimir) should not be too different from PCRE"** and I think that's your problem.  In particular, `+` is a metacharacter in PRCE, but not in BRE.  Observe:

```
echo '==+++++' | grep ^==+*
==+++++

echo '==+++++' | grep -E ^==+*
grep: repetition-operator operand invalid
```

The `-E` on `grep` enables extended regex.

So, now that you know that `+` is just a literal `+` under BRE, can you see why all of your patterns behave the way they do?